# LM3478/LM5155 configuration on a wide input and output voltage range

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, ltspice, output, switching-regulator

In [my last question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542453/switching-between-three-output-voltage-settings-on-a-switching-regulator) I mentioned the case of obtaining different output voltages from a single switching regulator. I ended up running a successful simulation of such setup in LTSpice using MC34063 and mosfet transistors to switch the feedback resistor and set the output voltage based on the input from a CD4017 counter.

Now, I would like to do a similar thing on a higher power regulator like LM3478 or LM51551 chosen based on the TI's WEBENCH Power Designer online.

I ended up setting up both models in the LTSpice to simulate it like previously and they seem to work right, however just for the initial Vin and Vout settings. After changing the resistor pair or setting different voltage input the whole thing either does not manage to obtain the set output or is completely off in terms of its performance. My guess is that it is due to the fact, that these ICs are more complex in their configuration than the MC34063 used before in the learning process.

Also, my input is to be such as:
Case 1: 6.4V Battery - 8V, 10V and 12V settings possible;
Case 2: 12.8V Battery - 15v, 20V, 25V settings on the output.
All based on one circuit with proper analog logic and jumpers applied to switch between these cases.

Do you think it is possible to obtain a viable configuration operating on these wide ranges using these kind of voltage regulators with complex setup? Is there any widely used, high power, but simpler to configure switching regulator which would be a valuable option to look at in this use-case?

I'll appreciate any advice on that. Below is a picture of the configuration with LM3478 from LTSpice.

[image: schematic]

Comment: What's your idea of "high power"? What sort of output current range are you looking for? And why don't you examine the simulation to see why it's not working the way you want?

Comment: I would reccoment building this circuit on a breadboard instead of the simulation. It seems like the simulation is failing (since you only change some resistors and it does not output what you want). Can you be more specific of what resistors you are changing any why?

Comment: Have you done the math on this? I don't do SMPS designs, but I do know that there are combinations of loads, inductors and frequencies that will not work. For example, if the inductor is not sized appropriately for the switching frequency, it may not be able to switch fast enough to drive large loads. The question you are asking involves a few chapters in an SMPS book.

Comment: Well this setup is created automatically for the 25V/2A assumed output. And it works for such setting of the v_out. However it does not work for other values applied, when the Rfb2 resistor's value is changed. I previously found some advice, that in case of a need for operation on a range of values of v_out, the initial assumptions of the regulator's circuit should be based on the situation when v_out takes the highest value on the range - in my case 25V. 
Do you guys have any advice for a kind, model of switching regulator which would be fitting my use-case with the ranges described above?